# Stylizing button with class reference does'nt work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate famous buttons, but when I style a single button using its class it doesn't style

```css
button {
  color: blue;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.yt button {
  color: red;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="yt">Subscribe</button>
<button class="join">Join</button>
<button class="tweet">Tweet</button>
```

[Image of Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIglp.png):

[image]

Comment: you want `button.yt` to refer to element type with specific class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use button.yt

```css
button {
    color: blue;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

button.yt{
    color: red;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="yt">Subscribe</button>
    <button class="join">Join</button>
    <button class="tweet">Tweet</button>
</body>
</html>
```